# Get parent of clicked element and find a child with class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
         <div>
             <div class="circle"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div>
             <div class="square"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is a simple and reduced example of my code.

On click of circle I need to get square. The above code block appears a few times on my page. So I need to get the parent of element clicked and find it's square child.

I have tried both of these:

```
$('.circle').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.square');
    $(this).parents('.container').find('.square');
});
```

How can I find the square using jquery?

Comment: looks good, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('.circle').click(function(e){
   var square = $(this).closest('.container').find('.square');
   console.log(square.text());
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukcd9jmx/)

Comment: This is the best answer because it's the most flexible to future possible changes in the HTML, as long as the class name stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `parentsUntil()`, like described here: [parentsUntil](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

```
$('.circle').click(function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil('.container').find('.square');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.circle').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.container').find('.square');
});
```

Working JS Fiddle with an example alerting text content of square element when clicking circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/v2Lw9vd8/